# manually create a scope for registered services

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

Below is an example:

```
//startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
 services.AddScoped<IMyScopedService, MyScopedService>();

 services.AddScoped<AnotherScopedService , AnotherScopedService >();

 var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

 var serviceScopeFactory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

 IMyScopedService scopedOne;
 IMyScopedService scopedTwo;
 IMyScopedService scopedThree;
 IMyScopedService scopedFour;

 using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
 {
    scopedOne = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMyScopedService>();
    scopedTwo = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMyScopedService>();
 }

 using (var scope = serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
 {
    scopedThree = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IMyScopedService>();
 }

 scopedFour = serviceProvider.GetService<IMyScopedService>();

 AnotherScopedService.getSomething(app.ApplicationServices);
}


//AnotherScopedService .cs
public class AnotherScopedService 
{
   ...
   public static void getSomething(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
      IMyScopedService scopedFive = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyScopedService>();
      ...
   }
}
```

I understand that `scopedOne` and `scopedTwo` are actually the same object becuase they were created under the same scope, and `scopedThree` is a different object than `scopedOne` and `scopedTwo`.

Below is my questions:

Q1-under which scope `scopedFour` was created? I didn't manually create a scope for `scopedFour`, so does `scopedFour` get created by `ConfigureServices` method's scope?

Q2-what about `scopedFour` and `scopedFive`, under which scope they were created?

Comment: @John  what is global container?

Comment: @John so it is the same scope of the `ConfigureServices` method? could you tell me the official name of the container  so I can google it and study

Comment: I'm not sure what it's called. It's just the built-in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection container that comes as default with ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't read the code for this myself but I believe that this is how it works based on other DI containers I've worked with. I don't typically use the default one in ASP.NET Core because it's a little limited for my purposes.

The ASP.NET Core host builder automatically creates a dependency injection container. This effectively has a root scope which lasts from when you create the container to when you destroy it (i.e. when your application shuts down).

In absence of a more specific scope, this is the scope that will be used. In both of your examples, the same case applies - they are created without a more specific scope.

Note that when I try your code, I can't instantiate a scoped service from `ApplicationServices`. I get the following error:

> 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'TestObject' from root provider.'

Which suggests that this isn't possible without a scope in this context.

You can explore how it works internally by reading the code [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/tree/master/src/DependencyInjection/DI).

Comment: so you mean `scopedFour` and `scopedFive` were all created under the DI container's root scope?

Comment: I think you just confirmed that `scopedFour` and `scopedFive` were all created under the DI container's root scope?

Comment: If you resolve a scoped service twice from the same container using `GetRequiredService` or `GetService` without a scope, you will get the _same instance_ meaning that the container keeps a record of it in its root scope. I did find that I wasn't able to resolve this from `app.ApplicationServices` because I got an error, so I'm not convinced that your sample code works.

Comment: so does life time of root scope is "Singleton"? if yes, that menas every service we register as `.AddSingleton` are created under root scope?

Comment: Singleton is a different concept. A singleton will be registered with the root scope and will be a unique instance in your application. Your root-scope resolved Scoped-registered services are not singletons not. A different scope will resolve a different instance for these.

Comment: I didn't mean scoped-registered services, I mean services registered as "Singleton", those services were under root scope, am I correct?

Comment: and if I register a service as `services.AddTransient<MyClass, MyClass>`, when an instance of `MyClass` is required in the application, this instance will be created under "transient scope" which is created by DI container, am I correct?